# How to get the most possible pairs from a list

Tags: c++, tuples

I have a list of Integer with increasing numbers (in order, no duplicates) like

3, 5, 11, 16, 25, 33, 40

I want to know how many pairs I could create with the following condition:

- the difference between the two numbers can not be lower then 7
- the difference between the two numbers can not be higher then 17
- I can use every number only once

With above example I could create the following pairs (ignoring the last condition)
(3, 11)
(3, 16)
(5, 16)
(11, 25)
(16, 25)
(16, 33)
(25, 33)
(25, 40)
(33, 40)

But as I can use every number only once, I could get for example
(3, 16)
(25, 33)
**or**
(3, 11)
(5, 16)
(33, 40)

What I want, would be the second example, because it's the most possible count of pairs I could get.

What I have so far:

```
int CountPairs( std::vector< int > listInt )
{
   std::vector< std::tuple< int, int > > listPairs;

   for( std::vector<int>::const_iterator iter = listInt.begin();
      iter != listInt.end();
      ++iter )
   {
      int val = *iter;
      std::vector<int>::const_iterator compareIter = iter;
      compareIter++;

      for( ; compareIter != listInt.end(); ++compareIter )
      {
         int compareVal = *compareIter;

         int result = compareVal - val;

         if( result >= 7 && result <= 17 )
         {
            listPairs.push_back( make_tuple( val, compareVal ) );
         }

         if( result > 17 )
            break;
      }
   }

   if( listPairs.size() <= 1 )
   {
      return listPairs.size();
   }

   //...
}
```

After this I have at least a list of all possible combinations, but I am not sure how to proceed or if there is a better way.

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please ask a more specific question about where you are blocked? In your case you are interested in filtering a list of pairs depending on a condition, you should start with that as you have already got the generation part done.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no memory constraints, you can use temporary structure, which will hold unused numbers

```
std::vector<int> temp(listInt); // copy ctor
std::vector<std::tuple<int,int>> listPairs;

while (temp.size() > 1)
{
 for (auto it = temp.begin(); it != temp.end(); it++)
 {
   auto diff = *it - temp.front();
   if (diff >= 7 && diff <= 17)
   {
     listPairs.push_back(make_tuple(temp.front(), *it));
     temp.erase(it);
     break;
   }
 }
 temp.erase(temp.begin());
}
```

The time spend on copying array may have better time-results, than repeatly searching used numbers. Moreover I think this code is much cleaner.

There are other quirks with dynamic reallocation of vector, so you should investigate which container is good one.

The worst case scenario for this algorithm is list of values, not matching the constraints (for example values with distance above 17 each one). You must consider how probable it is.

Comment: As you said, this might not be the perfect solution in those worst case scenarios, but for my problem it should be good enough, as it is less likely to have values below 7 and if all the distances are that big to not find a match, the number of elements in the list will be quite small. I will try it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am interested in your problem, I spent a little time there to try another algo.
The principle is to assess the number of connections of each node and to favor those with the least connection.

I'm used to code in c but here C++ would have been a much better solution.
I couldn't find a counter example

https://godbolt.org/z/HsyPCa

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

#define ABS(a) ((a)<0?-(a):(a));
#define LOW_CONSTRAINT  7
#define UP_CONSTRAINT   17

const int testVals[] = {3, 10, 11, 17, 18};
#define VALCOUNT (sizeof(testVals)/sizeof(int))

typedef enum {
    nodeFree,
    nodePaired,
    nodeDrop
} nodeState_t;

typedef struct searchNode_t
{
    int val;
    nodeState_t state;
    struct searchNode_t* foundPair;
    int pairsCount;
    struct searchNode_t* pairs[2*(UP_CONSTRAINT-LOW_CONSTRAINT+1)];
} searchNode_t;

void printVals()
{
    int i;
    printf("{");
    for (i = 0; i<VALCOUNT; i++)
    {
        printf("%d,", testVals[i]);
    }
    printf("}\n");
}

void printPairs(searchNode_t* nodes[], int nodecount)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i<nodecount; i++)
    {
        searchNode_t* currentN = nodes[i];
        printf("\nPairs for %d:\n", currentN->val);
        for (j = 0; j<currentN->pairsCount; j++)
        {
            printf("(%d : %d)\n", currentN->val, currentN->pairs[j]->val);
        }
    }
}

int nodesScore(searchNode_t* node1, searchNode_t* node2)
{
    return ABS(node1->val - node2->val)
}

int nodeBestScore(searchNode_t* node)
{
    if (node->pairsCount == 0)
        return UP_CONSTRAINT;
    return nodesScore(node, node->pairs[0]);
}

int firstFreeNodeIndex(searchNode_t* nodes[], int arraySize)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<arraySize; i++)
    {
        if (nodes[i]->state == nodeFree)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

void insertNodeSortUpward(searchNode_t* parentNode, searchNode_t* childNode)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < (parentNode->pairsCount); i++)
    {
        if (childNode->val < parentNode->pairs[i]->val)
        {
            memmove(&parentNode->pairs[i], &parentNode->pairs[i+1], sizeof(searchNode_t*)*((parentNode->pairsCount)-i-1));
            break;
        }
    }
    parentNode->pairs[i] = childNode;
    parentNode->pairsCount += 1;
}


void main (void)
{
    int i, j;
    searchNode_t nodesMem[VALCOUNT];
    searchNode_t* nodes[VALCOUNT];

    printf("\n\n*** values:\n");
    printVals();

    // Init nodes
    for (i=0; i<VALCOUNT; i++)
    {
        nodesMem[i] = (searchNode_t){.val=testVals[i], .state=nodeFree, .pairsCount=0, .foundPair = NULL, .pairs={NULL}};
        nodes[i] = &nodesMem[i];
    }

    // Compute scores
    for (i = 0; i<VALCOUNT; i++)
    {
        searchNode_t* currentN = nodes[i];
        for (j = 0; j<VALCOUNT; j++)
        {
            searchNode_t* pairNode = nodes[j];
            int delta;

            // don't compare node to itself
            if (currentN == pairNode)
                continue;

            delta = nodesScore(currentN, pairNode);
            if ((delta>=LOW_CONSTRAINT) && (delta <=UP_CONSTRAINT))
            {
                insertNodeSortUpward(currentN, pairNode);
            }

        }
    }

    printf("\n\n*** Available pairs:\n");
    printPairs(nodes, VALCOUNT);

    printf("\n\n*** Searching best pairs:\n");
    searchNode_t* bestNode;
    int foundPairsCount = 0;
    searchNode_t* foundPairs[VALCOUNT];
    int droppedNodesCount = 0;
    searchNode_t* droppedNodes[VALCOUNT];

    while (1)
    {
        int firstNode = firstFreeNodeIndex(nodes, VALCOUNT);
        if (firstNode < 0)
            break;
        bestNode = nodes[firstNode];

        for (i = 1; i<VALCOUNT; i++)
        {
            if (nodes[i]->state == nodeFree)
            {
                if (bestNode->pairsCount > nodes[i]->pairsCount)
                {
                    bestNode = nodes[i];
                }
            }
        }
        printf("Best node is %d\n", bestNode->val);

        // pair nodes if availables
        int foundIndex = firstFreeNodeIndex(bestNode->pairs, bestNode->pairsCount);
        if (foundIndex < 0)
        {
            bestNode->state = nodeDrop;
            droppedNodes[droppedNodesCount++] = bestNode;
        }
        else
        {
            bestNode->state = nodePaired;
            bestNode->foundPair = bestNode->pairs[foundIndex];
            bestNode->pairs[foundIndex]->state = nodePaired;
            bestNode->pairs[foundIndex]->foundPair = bestNode ;
            printf("Found pair (%d : %d)\n", bestNode->val, bestNode->foundPair->val);
            foundPairs[foundPairsCount++] = bestNode;
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n*** Summary:\n");
    printf("Algorithm found %d pairs:\n", foundPairsCount);
    for (i = 0; i<foundPairsCount; i++)
    {
        printf("(%d : %d)\n", foundPairs[i]->val, foundPairs[i]->foundPair->val);
    }
    printf("\nAlgorithm dropped %d values:\n", droppedNodesCount);
    for (i = 0; i<droppedNodesCount; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", droppedNodes[i]->val);
    }
}
```